# How can I add logic to an existing dependency-property callback?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dependency-properties, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to add a PropertyChangedCallback to UIElement.RenderTransformOriginProperty. An exception is thrown when I try to override the PropertyMetadata.

I have searched MSDN and Google, and all I have been able to come up with is [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d2aa5151-901e-47b7-9a0d-955214737b7f). DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged is suggested at some point in that post, but that won't solve my problem since this is not a per-instance callback.

I don't understand what this exception means at all. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
public class foo : FrameworkElement
{
    private static void Origin_Changed( DependencyObject d,
                                        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    { }

    static foo()
    {
        PropertyMetadata OriginalMetaData =
            UIElement.RenderTransformOriginProperty.GetMetadata(
                typeof(FrameworkElement));



/*An exception is thrown when this line is executed:
 "Cannot change property metadata after it has been associated with a property"*/
        OriginalMetaData.PropertyChangedCallback +=
            new PropertyChangedCallback(Origin_Changed);



        UIElement.RenderTransformOriginProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(foo), OriginalMetaData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

WPF will merge the property metadata for you when you call OverrideMetadata, no need to pass it the original Metadata object. So all you have to do is

```
UIElement.RenderTransformOriginProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(foo), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(Origin_Changed)));
```

One thing to be aware of is sometimes the code above throws an exception. The two cases where that happens are

**1.** The original metadata is a subclass of PropertyMetadata - I have seen FrameworkPropertyMetadata and UIPropertyMetadata. You just have to use the appropriate one in each case.

**2.** The dependency property is read only and you can't do anything about it.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks! I tend to assume the framework isn't going to do that kind of work for me automatically. I guess it's just the ocupational hazard of being a low-level engineer in the era of high-level dominance ...

Comment: Hehe, I can sympathize with that. I spent countless hours trying to bend WPF from a Win32 programmer perspective when I couldn't work out the "cosher" WPF way.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Oh dang, that throws me off a little bit - I need to listen for changes to some read-only FrameworkElement dependency-properties, as well... This being the case, what would you suggest? I really, REALLY don't want to try to implement it using AddValueChanged on every instance of my class. Although, I guess I wouldn't mind, as long as it doesn't have any performance hit - versus PropertyChangedCallback. Alas, this needs to be efficient, by all means.

Comment: When I said read only I meant the dependency property metadata cannot be overriden. You will get an exception when trying to call OverrideMetadata. If that is the case you can't do much I am afraid.

Comment: Does it matter where you place this code ? 
For instance could i create a static contractor in some object in my wpf application and when compiling it will merge the meta data with the one from the framework with the default settings , 
or do i have to subclass the FrameworkElement witch i would like it to effect  ?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618402/how-to-override-metadata-for-a-dependency-property) SO question for the place you need to put the above code