# WPF - Updating DependencyProperty Metadata

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

What is the technical reason for not being able to update a DependencyProperty's metadata after it has already been set?

If you try to do something similar to below it will generate an exception saying:

> Cannot change property metadata after it has been associated with a property.

```
MyProperty.DefaultMetata.PropertyChangedCallback = 
    new PropertyChangedCallback(MyMethod);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutable objects have many benefits, one of which is thread-safety.

Also, metadata exists on a per-type basis; setting `PropertyChangedCallback` directly would effectively erase all other callbacks in the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Does this question from Stackoverflow help any.  [WPF Property Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310090/how-can-i-add-logic-to-an-existing-dependency-property-callback)

If that doesn't help. What do you mean by set, set in vs2k8 dev or set in the dll.